# Script to "click" on a drawn button on a Google Sheet for Analytics v4 Report?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a Google Sheets Apps Script question related to an extension I use. We use Google Analytics v4 for data on our app's activity, and I pull daily numbers on that into a Google Sheet to create reports. Google made a free extension to do that for GA v3, but not for v4, and so I have to use an extension called Google Analytics Connector by SyncWith in order to get the data. It gives you 35 free report refreshes per month before it locks down and makes you pay to get any more, so I have to be very specific about only refreshing once a day (my company is not going to pay for a monthly plan from them). SyncWith has an automatic daily refresh setting, but the problem is it doesn't let you pick the specific time that it refreshes.

SyncWith makes spreadsheets for its reports, and originally had a TRUE/FALSE checkbox at the top. When you checked it, it would execute their code to pull in the new day's numbers from GA v4. I made this simple Apps Script that would simply check the box and uncheck it to get the report to run, and had a trigger set to run the Apps Script between 6 and 7 a.m.

```
function AppDataRefresh() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('App Daily data');
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue("TRUE");
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue("FALSE");
}
```

However, now SyncWith has replaced its checkboxes with a new panel at the top that uses drawn buttons. This is what it looks like: https://freeimage.host/i/H7FfrEF

So, unfortunately, there's no longer any checkbox, meaning I can't get this report generated automatically at a specific time with my original Apps Script fix. So, my question is, based on the above picture, is there any kind of an Apps Script that can simulate clicking on a drawn button in a Google Sheet, based on cell location? For example, is there an Apps Script that could click "Refresh" by just clicking on cell D1?

Comment: If that's as straight forward as it seems, click on the button with the right button, get the name of the function that the button calls. Replace `sheet.getRange('A1').setValue("TRUE");` with that function's name: `functionName()` When running `AppDataRefresh()` it should get the function referenced run.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! When I checked the "Refresh" button, it showed the assigned function was "__SW_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS__Refresh_0"

I changed my AppScript to this:

`function AppDataRefreshV2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('App Daily data');
  __SW_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS__Refresh_0();
}`

And I received this error:

`ReferenceError: __SW_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS__Refresh_0 is not defined
AppDataRefreshV2 @ AppDataRefreshV2.gs:3`